# Arrange Images in two columns and number of rows in Collection View both in Portrait and Landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

How to arrange images in two columns for each rows in `CollectionView`, both in Portrait and Landscape modes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    float cellWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame) - (flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right) - flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing) / 2;
    return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);
}
```

Happy coding...